# control system - is the gain positive or negative?

Tags: frequency, control-system, bode-plot, frequency-response

If the phase of a control system at high frequencies approaches to 0º then its gain K is negative. And if it approaches to -180º it gain is positive? Why is that? And how it works for low frequencies? Does anybody here know where can I find information about it?

The transfer function of the control system:

[image: transfer function]

Phase result (request by @AJN):
[image: example]

Comment: What controls system? Include a diagram. There are plenty of books about control systems and linear systems. But we don't do book recommendations here.

Comment: This may not be true. Where did you read this?

Comment: Imagine a double integrator. Its phase at high frequency is 180 when the *"gain"* is positive.

Comment: @AJN I put an example above

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I edited it

Comment: Are you familiar with finding gain and phase of a transfer function for a given value of `s=j.w` ? If so, do it for this example. One with positive K and one with negative K. Take `s=100000j` to do the calculation. Please add the result to the question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: @AJN did it. But how do I know if the k is positive or negative?

Comment: Simplest way us to try substituting a positive and later a negative value and checking which matches the result expected. It is difficult without actually working it out, IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124804/discussion-between-ajn-and-lusvi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Given

Phase approaches \$\Phi\$ at *high* frequencies (or 0 frequency);
And a transfer function which you can **rewrite** in the form

$$
H(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)} = K \cdot \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (s-z_i)}{\prod_{j=1}^{m} (s-p_j)}
$$

### Finding the relation between angle and K

At *high* frequencies, \$s \rightarrow \jmath\infty\$ ans so \$s-c_i \approx s\$. So,
$$
\begin{align}
H(s)|_{s\rightarrow \jmath\infty} &{}\approx{}
K \cdot \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n} s}{\prod_{j=1}^{m} s}
= K \cdot s^{n-m}\\
%
\angle H(s)_{s\rightarrow \jmath\infty} &{}\approx{}
\angle K + \angle(\jmath \omega)^{n-m}
= \angle K + \angle(\jmath)^{n-m} = \color{blue}{\angle K + (n-m) \times 90\deg}
\end{align}
$$

\$\angle K = 0\$ if \$K \ge 0\$  and \$\angle K = 180\$ if \$K < 0\$.

At low frequencies, \$s \rightarrow \jmath 0\$ ans so \$s-c_i \approx -c_i\$. Similar derivation for the angle can be done for this case also.

### Your example

$$
H(s)|_{s\rightarrow \jmath\infty} {}\approx{}
K \frac{s}{s^3} \\
\angle H(s)|_{s\rightarrow \jmath\infty} {}\approx{}
\angle K + (1-3) \times 90 \deg = \angle K - 180 \deg
$$

So, if it was given that the angle approached -180 deg at high frequencies, then K would have been positive, so that it contributed 0 deg in the blue equation above.

**But**, your handwritten results show the reverse. I think it is because you have not taken the correct quadrant for the angle while taking \$\tan^{-1}\$ for the middle term \$\tan^{-1}(-100000/(8000\pi))\$.

See the below difference when taking `arctan`:

```matlab
>> atan2d(-100000, 8000)
ans = -85.426
>> atan2d(100000, -8000)
ans =  94.574
```

Comment: ohh thanks, now I have understood this

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the numerator phase angle. This is either \$\small\phi =atan\:(\frac{-\omega}{\omega_{1}})=-90^o\$, or \$\small \phi =atan\:(\frac{\omega}{-\omega_{1}})=90^o\$, as \$\small\omega\rightarrow \infty \$. The denominator phase angle will always be \$\small -270^o\$, as \$\small\omega\rightarrow \infty \$.

Comment: why -270º? And why in one you put w1 and in the other -w1 if it has the same phase?

Comment: Denominator is third order, each 1st order term contributes \$\small -90^o\$ as \$\omega \rightarrow \infty\$. Numerator is either \$j\omega -\omega_1\$ or \$-j\omega +\omega_1\$. This question is all about getting arctan in the correct quadrant.